# Get terminal width in Windows using golang

Tags: windows, go, terminal

Is it possible to get the terminal width in Go?

I tried using http://github.com/nsf/termbox-go with the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(termbox.Size())
}
```

But it prints `0 0`.

I also tried http://github.com/buger/goterm but when I try to `go get` it, I get an error:

```
$ go get github.com/buger/goterm
# github.com/buger/goterm
..\..\buger\goterm\terminal.go:78: undefined: syscall.SYS_IOCTL
..\..\buger\goterm\terminal.go:82: not enough arguments in call to syscall.Syscall
```

Any other ideas on how to get the terminal width?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `termbox.Init()` before you call `termbox.Size()`, and then `termbox.Close()` when you're done.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/nsf/termbox-go"
)

func main() {
    if err := termbox.Init(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    w, h := termbox.Size()
    termbox.Close()
    fmt.Println(w, h)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `twin` package:

```
package main
import "github.com/walles/moar/twin"

func main() {
   s, e := twin.NewScreen()
   if e != nil {
      panic(e)
   }
   w, h := s.Size()
   println(w, h)
}
```

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/walles/moar/twin#Screen